# Writing multiple functions in custom code in report rdlc

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I am trying to write 2 function definitions in rdlc custom code as below

```
 Public Function GetValue(ByVal total as Integer) As Integer
   total = total - (total * 0.04)   
   Return total 
 End Function 

 Public Function GetCalValue(By caltotal as Integer) As Integer
   caltotal = (caltotal - (caltotal * 0.04)) + (caltotal * 0.004)
   Return caltotal
 End Function
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
   Error    1   There is an error on line 5 of custom code: [BC30213] Comma or ')' expected.            
   C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsApplication3\WindowsApplication3\Report5.rdlc WindowsApplication3
```

Can someone please tell me what mistake i have committed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function GetCalValue(By caltotal as Integer) As Integer
```

"By" should be "ByVal"

```
Public Function GetCalValue(ByVal caltotal as Integer) As Integer
```

Comment: Yes it was a silly mistake. Thankyou so much for the help :)